# Runserver issues with Django in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm running Pycharm 2016.3.2 with Python 3.6 on Windows 10. I started up a django project, following the tutorial on the jetbrains website and when I try the command runserver from the manage.py view I get:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Really confusing to me considering I did nothing different than what the tutorial was telling me.  Running file from the command line with python manage.py runserver works perfectly. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: if you run this command in the command line does it work?

Comment: I wrote that it worked in my post above.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your current config?

Comment: @Lewis added the screenshot

Comment: Try starting a new configuration by going to: `Run -> Edit Configurations create new configuration`

`Script: path_to/manage.py`

`Script parameters: runserver`

Comment: Didn't make any noticeable change for me

Comment: Are you using PyCharm professional or the community edition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133295/discussion-between-geoffrey007-and-lewis).

Comment: just by chance, it is still running in the command on port 8000 while you are attempting to run in pycharm on same host:port?

Comment: Try unflagging "Test server". I really doubt if you need that flag ATM.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by a Microsoft bug. The solution is to add an environment variable as follows (this is a project specific setting; for instructions on how to configure global default setting see Jetbrains support link at bottom):

1. Open Run>Edit Configurations
2. In the Run/Debug Configurations window that opens, click on the far right button on the Environment Variables to open Environment Variables editing dialogue box.
3. In the name field enter: =C:
4. In the value field enter: c:\"
5. Click OK and then apply
6. From the Run menu select Run 'YouProjectName' and the Django server should start without a problem.

Here is a link to Jetbrains support with a discussion and more details on the problem and how to fix it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17069#comment=27-1803699&u=1482137902791

Hope this helps. If you still have any problems let me know.